# WooCommerce Worldpay shopper redirect URL

Tags: woocommerce, settings, payment-gateway

I've got this payment gateway running on a site, after checkout it's taking customers to the Worldpay hosted payments and then the payment is done. It is notifying of successful payment but not redirecting the shopper back to the order confirmation page on WooCommerce.

Does anyone know what I need to set as the Shopper Redirect URL in Worldpay for this to happen?

Comment: Better ask Wordpay support, as this is for sure about settings in Wordpay shop owner account or on the Wordpay plugin settings…

Comment: Please post code showing what you achieved so far and eventual error messages. So that one can point what problem is happening and be able to help.